# File contains path instead of text

Tags: windows, curl, webdav

I'm trying to transfer a file with curl and it's getting created on the remote server, however the file contents are the path to the file instead of the actual contents of the file.

```
curl -x "poxy" --user user:pass --verbose -X PUT --data-binary "@D:\test.txt" "url/test.txt"
```

On the server, I see test.txt get created but the contents are:

```
D:\test.txt
```

On the local machine, the contents of the file are:

```
hello world
```

Note this is on cURL for windows if it matters.